# How to add two Milliseconds in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, mobile

I want to calculate difference between two times which is calculate correctly then i have to half it so i divide it with 2 results are okay. but when i am trying to add the timdedifferencemillis to startTime its not giving me the correct result...

**starttime= 05:53

endtime= 17:57

i want results 11:55

but my code giving me 06:55**
please help.....

```
protected String transitTime2(String endtime, String starttime) {
    SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
    Date startTime = null;
    Date endTime;
    long timdedifferencemillis = 0;
    try {
        startTime = dt.parse(starttime);
        endTime = dt.parse(endtime);
        long diff=startTime.getTime();
        timdedifferencemillis = (endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime())/2;
        //timdedifferencemillis

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    long timdedifferencemillis1=startTime.getTime()+timdedifferencemillis;

    int minutes = Math
            .abs((int) ((timdedifferencemillis1 / (1000 * 60)) % 60));
    int hours = Math
            .abs((int) ((timdedifferencemillis1 / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24));
    String hmp = String.format("%02d %02d ", hours, minutes);
    return hmp;
}
```

Comment: 17:57 - 05:53 = 12:04. Why do you expect 11:55 and why are you dividing by 2?

Comment: Oh, you're trying to find the time halfway in between?

Comment: @DavidConrad yes your are right 12.04 is difference, its half is 06:02. Now i want to add 06:02 in startTime. so 05:53+06:02=11:55. Thats what i was trying to do if you can please suggest something...

Comment: There was TimeZone problem i got this from below answer now it is working accurately....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably time zone; when you parse `endtime` and `starttime` initially, by default (in the absence of an explicit time zone indicated in the format string and represented in the input), Java assumes that the times provided are relative to the **local time zone** of the system.  Then, when you call [`getTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29), it returns

> the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 **GMT** represented by this `Date` object

One solution is to tell your `SimpleDateFormat` object to assume that all strings it parses are in GMT, rather than in the local time zone. Try adding this line after you initialize `dt`, but before calling `dt.parse(...)`:

```
dt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easy to do with the new `java.time` API in Java 8 or with the JODA Time library:

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalTime;

public class TimeDiff {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse("05:53");
        LocalTime end = LocalTime.parse("17:57");
        // find the duration between the start and end times
        Duration duration = Duration.between(start, end);
        // add half the duration to the start time to find the midpoint
        LocalTime midPoint = start.plus(duration.dividedBy(2));
        System.out.println(midPoint);
    }
}
```

Output:

> 11:55

By using `LocalTime` objects, you avoid any problems with time zones.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the types "long" and "int" in your code ;when we divide with 2 ( long timdedifferencemillis )the result must be "double".